# How to convert string equation to number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to convert string equation to number in javascript?

Say I have "100*100" or "100x100" how do I evaluate that and convert to a number?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not homework, I'm attempting to convert lot sizes into the longforms from shorthand directly at the user input. I have tried eval() and parseInt and parseFloat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you the product whether the string is using `*` or `x`:

```
var str = "100x100";

var tmp_arr = str.split(/[*x]/);
var product = tmp_arr[0]*tmp_arr[1];   // 10000
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're sure that the string will always be something like "100*100" you could `eval()` it, although most people will tell you this isn't a good idea on account of the fact that people could pass in malicious code to be eval'd.

```
eval("100*100");
>> 10000
```

Otherwise, you'll have to find or write a custom equation parser. In that case, you might want to take a look at the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), and read up on [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

---

Using `split()`:

```
var myEquation = "100*100";
var num = myEquation.split("*")[0] * myEquation.split("*")[1];
>> 10000
```

Comment: Is there a way to split it by the x and the numbers,and multiply just the numbers? Would split work for that?

Answer (score 1):

One Liner:

```
str.split(/[x*]/).reduce((a,b) => a*b)
```

Answer (score 0):

use parseInt() ,The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

```
        parseInt("100")*parseInt("100") //10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different take on the users answers here that gives an output using split but also recreates the original equation. The other answers I saw used split but didn't really give a correlation that could be parameterized of the original equation in starting out as string format.

Using `split()` and `for` is NOT a good solution but I use it here to illustrate the better solution that doesn't require knowing the number of numbers in the array (which would be reduce). The reason why this works is that in effect it acts like reduce but it requires you to edit the for loop multiplier based on how large the array is:

```js
let someEnvironmentVariable = '3*3*3'
let equationString = someEnvironmentVariable;
// regex to match anything in the set i.e. * and + << not sure if need the ending +
let re = /[\*\+]+/;
let equationToNumberArray = equationString.split(re).map(Number);
let equationResolver = 0;
for (const numericItem of equationToNumberArray) {
  // recreate the equation above
  equationResolver += numericItem*numericItem;
}

console.log(equationResolver);
```

A more elegant solution would be to use:
`split()`, `map()` and `reduce()`

```js
let someEnvironmentVariable = '3*3*4*3'
let equationString = someEnvironmentVariable;
// regex to match anything in the set i.e. * and + << not sure if need the ending +
let re = /[\*\+]+/;
let equationToNumberArray = equationString.split(re).map(Number);

let arrayMultiplier = equationToNumberArray.reduce((a, b) => a * b);

console.log(arrayMultiplier);
```

Using reduce allows you to iterate through the array and perform a calculation on each item while maintaining the previous calculation on the previous item.

Note: what I don't like about either solution is that even reduce requires only one mathematical operation for an array set. A better solution would be code something that detects the operators and includes that in the overall solution
This allows you to not use the dreaded `eval()` but also keep the original equation intact for later processing.