# How do I convert every string in split array to a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string that needs to be split and converted into numbers. I decided to split the string and put the strings into an array and later convert them into numbers using the `Array.prototype.every()` function and the `Number()` function.

When I check the type of the first array element, I see that I still have a string and not a number. Where is my mistake? The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286386/how-to-convert-string-equation-to-number-in-javascript) makes it look like after splitting JS would convert to number automatically but that isn't happening as evidenced by logging the type of the first element.

```
function detectOutlierValue(string) {
    // convert string into array with numbers, 'separator " "
    var numArray = string.split(' ');
    console.log(typeof numArray[0]);
    console.log(numArray);

    numArray.every(function (item) {
        return Number(item);
    });
    console.log(numArray, typeof numArray[0]);
```

My output is:

```
string
[ '2', '4', '7', '8', '10' ]
[ '2', '4', '7', '8', '10' ] 'string'
```

Comment: That's not how you use `every`...

Comment: Could you specify where the issue is?

Comment: 1. you are doing mistake in splitting.
2. `every()` is not used like this.
3. you need to use `parseInt()` to convert string to numbers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your array methods confused. [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is used to determine if *every* element in an array satisfies a certain condition specified by the callback. Basically, your code is converting every element to a number and then to a boolean for `every`, and `every` will return a boolean if the callback returns true for every element it's called on.

Instead, you are looking for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which performs a function on each element, mapping them to a new value:

```
var splitString = string.split(' ');
var numArray = splitString.map(Number);
```

This will map the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor (which is the callback) to every element converting it to a number. Note that `numArray` holds the transformed array, but `splitString` still contains the array of strings. `Number` will return `NaN` if the string is not numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `every` incorrectly. `every` tests to see if every element of an array is true for a certain condition.  So the function you have will be applied once for each element present in the array until it finds one where it returns a `falsy` value. If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false. What you want is `map`:

```js
function detectOutlierValue(string) {
  // convert string into array with numbers, 'separator " "
  var numArray = string.split(' ');
  console.log(typeof numArray[0]);
  console.log(numArray);

  numArray = numArray.map(function(item) {
    return Number(item);
  });

  console.log(numArray, typeof numArray[0]);
}

detectOutlierValue("1 2");
```

Here's probably what you wanted to do with `every`, but it's pointless because it's better to use `map`

```js
function detectOutlierValue(string) {
  // convert string into array with numbers, 'separator " "
  var numArray = string.split(' ');
  console.log(typeof numArray[0]);
  console.log(numArray);

  var newArr = [];

  numArray.every(function(item) {
    newArr.push(Number(item));
    return true;
  });

  console.log(newArr);
}

detectOutlierValue("1 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

So you shouldn't use `every()` method, instead you can do the following.

```js
var s = "2 3 4 7 8 10";

function detectOutlierValue(string){
// convert string into array with numbers, 'separator " "
 var numArray = string.split(' ');
  
  numArray.every(function (item){
  return Number(item);
 });
  console.log(numArray, typeof numArray[0]);
  
  for(var i=0; i<numArray.length; i++){
   numArray[i] = Number(numArray[i]);
  }
  console.log(numArray, typeof numArray[0]);
}  

detectOutlierValue(s);
```

Run the code and notice the difference between the two console outputs.

Answer (score 0):

`every` is meant to check if each element of an array passes some test.  For example:

```
function isAString(val) {
  return typeof val === 'string'
}
var array =     [ '2', '4', '7', '8', '10' ];
array.every(isAString) //returns true
```

What you want to do is use the `map` method

```
var array = [ '2', '4', '7', '8', '10' ];
var result = array.map(function (x) { 
  return Number(x); 
});
```